# How to join 2 tables without the unique key variables declared explicitly?

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many

JPA join 2 tables without the unique key variables declared explicitly?

I have these 2 tables where a student can borrow many books.

DB:

```
book
    - id
    - book_name
    - student_id
    
    
student
    -id
    -student_name
```

JPA:

*Book* entity :

```
  @Entity ("book")
    class Book {

    @Column ("book_name")
    private String bookName;
    
        @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
       private Student student;
    
    ..
    ..
    }
```

and *Student* entity:

```
  @Entity ("student")
    class Student {
    
    @Column ("student_name")
    private String student_name;
    
    
       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    private List <Book> book;
    ..
    }
```

For some reason it complains about

`org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find com.Student with id 7402`

Comment: Can you show the code where it does throw that exception?
And a couple more lines of the stacktrace?

Why are you not using an @Id field?

Answer (score 0):

The tables don't have such internal relation through any of *FK* fields. No join whatsoever eventhough the two tables clearly share the same column. This makes mapping operations on *JPA* side harder.

I ended up just declare such:

```
@Id
private Long id;
```

Beside this makes my entity much more readable.

And finally managing any *CRUD* operations through the Spring Data JPA's (`JpaRepository`). And utilize the `@Query` for retrieval as this annotations seems to be independent to the underlying table/schema relations.